# SQL Server query parse and compile time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to optimize run time of a stored procedure and whenever SQL Server is not picking up the plan from cache, I am seeing lot of time spent on compiling and parsing of the stored procedure. I took these stats using

```
SET Statistics TIME ON

EXEC [My_Stored_Proc_name] 

SET Statistics TIME OFF
```

SQL Server parse and compile time:

```
CPU time = 1170 ms, elapsed time = 1173 ms.
```

Out of total run time of 1860 ms, SP is spending 1170 ms in compiling the stored procedure. Is there a way to optimize the compile plans?

Note: the stored procedure is using around 30 + table joins.

Comment: How about the code for the procedure?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your proc is doing without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Is it really relevant that it takes about a second on the first time it executes? If it's used often, it should be cached. If it doesn't stay in cache (or is recompiled often) then you might have another problem.

Comment: It is little big stored procedure. I am looking for any guidelines or reasoning on how compile time will be calcuated

Comment: @Kris: Do you have SP:Recompile each time? Try to put code somewhere in internet and submit link. (I assure you: nobody will steal it). Common guidelines: #-tables -> SP:Recompile, a lot of quickly changing tables -> SP:Recompile. And: I suppose that 1170 ms is not recompile time - you have lock this time.